# Find a function $f$ which satisfies $f(mn) = f(m)f(n)$ for positive integers $m,n$ and $f(2)=2$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

We are to find a function f which follows the following properties
$$f(mn)=f(m)f(n),\; f(2)=2.$$

I can easily find all the values of $f(2^n)$ but I am confused on how to find for the odd numbers and the primes so as to find the function using induction. Please help.

Comment: $f(m)\leq f(n)$ under which assumptions on $m$ and $n$? Obviously, it cannot hold unconditionally.

Comment: Why not use the identity function?

Comment: John Douma , please elaborate your opinion.

Comment: It's not an opinion, it's a solution. Please finish it by doing your own work.

Comment: If i assume that the function that i am seeking is the identity function, then how can i use induction to check it for all the numbers. I can prove that f(1)  = 1 but assuming f(k)=k to be true i can't figure out how i am to prove f(k+1) is true too.

Comment: You don't need to use induction. You are just looking for a function with those properties. If $f(x) = x$, what can be said about $f(mn)$ and $f(2)$?

Comment: So you mean I do not have to prove it algebrically?

Comment: Is there any way by which we can f(3) using the given conditions with a proof?

Comment: Right. You only have to show that $f(mn) = f(m)f(n)$ and $f(2)=2$

Answer (score 2):

Let $g:\mathbb{P}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a given function with $g(2)=2$, in which $\mathbb{P}$ is set of all prime number. Define the function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as follow
$$f(n)=‎\prod_{i=1}^{k}g(p_{i})^{s_i}$$‎
where $n=\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_{i}^{s_i}$ factorises into distinct prime powers. Then 
$$f(mn)=f(n)f(m)$$
and $f(2)=2$. Therefore there is infinitly functions that satisfy in your functional equation.

**Hint.** This functional equation is called "[Multiplicative Arithmetic Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function)" and is an important branch of Theory of Arithmetic Functions and also there is a lot of results about this subject.

*R Sivaramakrishnan, Classical Theory of Arithmetic Functions, CRC Press*